# Java Endpoint class does not work with axis2 libraries

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I tried to google the answer to this question and checked related topics in StackOverFlow, but could not find anything helping to resolve this issue.

I am trying to use Java 7 Endpoint class. My simple code works fine:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService

public class TestWebService {

@WebMethod
public void printName(String name) {
    System.out.println("Hello " + name);
}
}
```

And my main:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class Main {

public static void main(String Args[]){
    Endpoint endPoint = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8099/andy", new     TestWebService());       
}
}
```

But when I add axis2 libraries to my project and run it I get the following error when I try to access my endpoint through the browser (or SoapUI)
Can any body tell me how to fix this issue?

```
<Exception>org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) /services/
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPhase.java:65)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:333)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:163)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:130)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPWorker.service(HTTPWorker.java:257)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.AxisHttpService.doService(AxisHttpService.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.AxisHttpService.handleRequest(AxisHttpService.java:187)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.HttpServiceProcessor.run(HttpServiceProcessor.java:82)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:575)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
</Exception>
```